# Wrong margin-top after editing wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout, margin

I have a wordpress website. After I edit any page in wordpress, a space between top of browser and menu becomes bigger. After I clean cash, the margin-top is good. It happens only in Safari (for desktop, in mobile Safari everything is good).

```
body {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 12px 12px 0px 12px;
    font-size: 11.5px;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
  }

\\menu
.main-navigation {
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    padding-right: 12px;
  }
```

I use media queries for different displays.
After the menu I have display:none sentence between

which is shown only on mobile devices.

Comment: It's possibly related to the admin toolbar.  Go into your user settings and uncheck "Show Toolbar when viewing site" and see if that helps.  The toolbar may be hidden by CSS but the Wordpress template is still making an offset for it?

Comment: It works! I unchecked "Show Toolbar" and now I don't have the space. Thanks a lot!